# Write a program to toggle a bit a position = “pos” in a number “n”

Tags: toggle

package setBitToToggle;
import java.util.*;
public class SetBitToToggle {`enter code here`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Write a program to toggle a bit a position = “pos” in a number “n”.
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=5;//0101.
    int pos=sc.nextInt();
    int bitmask=1<<pos;
    int newnumber=bitmask | n;
    System.out.println(newnumber);
    

}
enter code here
```

}

//What is the right code according to the question ?? I am unable to understand the question, //help me to understand the question

Answer (score 0):

1. Take number "n" and position "pos" as input from user.
2. For toggle(Replace 0->1 and 1->0) number of a bit at given postion.
   i) Bitmask : **1<<pos**
   ii) Operation : **XOR**(^)

For Example, if n = 5(101) & pos = 1, then answer should be 7(111).

```
class Toggle
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int pos=sc.nextInt();
        int bitmask=1<<pos;
        int newnumber=bitmask ^ n;
        System.out.println(newnumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For toggle a bit a position = “pos” in a number “n” ,use [**XOR** bit wise operator.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-java/)

```
public class toggle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=5;
    int pos = sc.nextInt();
    int bitmask= 1<<pos;
    int newNumber = bitmask ^ n;
    System.out.println(newNumber);
}
```

}